# Equivalent to alt-. in terminal

Tags: keyboard, terminal

I am curious as to whether there is an equivalent to the <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>.</kbd> command on Mac. On my computer it inserts the following character: ≥, instead of showing the [preceding lines final parameter](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6/what-are-your-favorite-command-line-features-or-tricks/69#69).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<kbd>ESC</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> inserts the last argument, quite similar like <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> on Linux

see https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/85152/31470

Comment: It's not exactly equivalent, because you can't for example press period twice while holding escape. The reason why using option as a meta key is disabled by default might be that many keyboard layouts have commonly used characters under option.

Answer (score 10):

You have to change the Terminal’s behavior to the <kbd>alt</kbd> key acts as a meta key (like in X11 Terms). After you check that, everytime you press <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>, you’ll get the last argument from the previous command. (You can repeat that command n times)

[image: Terminal Preferences]

Comment: That is pretty sweet. Is there any reason why I don't want to turn that option on?

Comment: If you wanted to use the OS X extended characters, for example: alt + . = …  or put a Copyright © (alt + c), you would have to find another way to do it, because your ALT key won’t cut it anymore ;) Other than that, if you work with the command line a lot, it’s a good idea to have it checked.