# How to have ctrl-left/ctrl-right move over words in Lion

Tags: macos, terminal, emacs

Had a quick question about having emacs-like word skipping in my terminal. I had [set this up](http://www.mattvsworld.com/blog/2010/03/word-movement-in-mac-os-x-terminal-bash-ctrl-left-and-ctrl-right/) pre-upgrade to Lion and had `ctrl-left` & `ctrl-right` set to `\033b` & `\033f` respectively.  Unfortunately post-upgrade `ctrl-left` & `ctrl-right` don't seem to be working any more.

I have seen [this solution](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1626/os-x-terminal-equivalent-of-ctrlleft-ctrlright) which makes `alt-left` & `alt-right` behave as above, but I was hoping to get `ctrl-left` & `ctrl-right` working as before and I was wondering if folks here had any solutions.

PS: As an aside this behavior is not working correctly in my [VNC client](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cotvnc/) as well - which it did previously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that Mission Control(in Lion) has the same key combination to `Move left a space` and `Move right a space` - which I particularly don't have use for. Disabling this in `Settings -> Keyboard Shortcuts` did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

⌃← and ⌃→ have moved a word left and right by default in Terminal since 10.7.

You can also change them in other applications by creating ~/Library/KeyBindings/ and saving this as DefaultKeyBinding.dict:

```
{
    "^\UF702" = moveWordLeft:;
    "^\UF703" = moveWordRight:;
}
```

Comment: I don't have a 'Library' under '~' and no 'KeyBindings' under '/Library'

Comment: ~/Library/ was hidden in 10.7, but you can open it from the go to folder sheet. There's no KeyBindings folder by default though.