# iTerm - going one word backwards and forwards

Tags: command-line, iterm

Would it be possible to configure iTerm 2 to go backwards and forwards one word through the curent text in the command line using a keyboard shortcut?

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question but it's relevant: you can option+click anywhere in a command line to move the cursor there.

Comment: @P-i- Why do you think that accepted answer is not the correct one? 1. It appeared almost 3 years before the one with most votes. 2. It presents a solution that doesn't works by default.

Comment: @P-i- You should only downvote a question if the question itself has problems, not because you disagree with OP's actions

Answer (score 103, accepted):

`Ctrl-[ b` jumps back a word. You can also use `Esc` instead or `Ctrl-[`, and `f` to go forward.

That is `Ctrl`+`[` release and then `b` or`f`.
Or `Esc` and `b` or `f`.

More information can be found at [this other discussion](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1626/os-x-terminal-equivalent-of-ctrlleft-ctrlright/1627#1627) on AskDifferent.

Comment: This would be better if there was a way to go back lots of words quickly while holding down a button, as opposed to having to type a sequence of keys for each word.

Comment: What is "Ctrl-[" ?

Comment: With "Ctrl-[ " I mean hitting the "Ctrl" key and "[" key simultaneously.

Comment: Answer below by Ricardo Stuven is the right answer

Comment: Yes, Just vist the next answer but not the adpoted one.

Answer (score 1318):

Killing a fly with a cannon:

1. Go to **iTerm2** (in the menu bar) > **Settings...** > **Profiles** > **Keys** (not "Preferences... > Keys"!),
2. On current versions (since version 3.4.9): switch to the **Key Mappings** tab,
3. Press **Presets...** dropdown button,
4. Select **Natural Text Editing**.

[image: screenshot of dialog with Presets]

Then, you can

- move a word backwards <kbd>Option ⌥</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd>
- move a word forwards <kbd>Option ⌥</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd>
- move to the start of the line <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd>
- move to the end of the line <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd>
- delete a word backwards <kbd>Option ⌥</kbd> + <kbd>⌫</kbd>
- delete the whole line <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⌫</kbd>

If the preset doesn't appear, reinstall iTerm2. If you installed it using Homebrew+Cask:

```bash
brew cask reinstall iterm2
```

or since [Homebrew 2.6.0](https://brew.sh/2020/12/01/homebrew-2.6.0/) (December 2020)

```bash
brew reinstall --cask iterm2
```

Comment: This is great and will add most of your needs. It however does not add a 'go to start/end of line via CMD + left arrow/right arrow`. For that action, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205157/iterm-2-how-to-set-keyboard-shortcuts-to-jump-to-beginning-end-of-line

Comment: Only issue is that say you have to ssh into a remote box, you need to know the standard terminal shortcuts. I just discovered this was possible now and was like "whoa why have I been twisting my fingers into `ctrl+w` to backspace a word, but on second thought, maybe its good to keep the muscle memory of the standard ones.

Comment: this is a better answer but i got a side effect: now `CMD+arrow-key` moves the cursor to the start/end of line (similar to `Option + arrow-key`) instead of navigating between iterm tabs.

Comment: Go to iTerm Preferences → Profiles, select your profile, then the Keys tab. Click Load Preset... and choose Natural Text Editing.

Comment: THANKS, this has to be the correct/verified answer!. ✌

Comment: With the new versions you'll need to go to `Key Mappings` then select a preset. You could also use `Terminal.app Compatibility` which gives the same result.

Comment: @Ibrahim.H Thanks, this worked for me! iTerm2 v. 3.4.10 installed via brew.

Comment: "Natural Text Editing" breaks the `fn + backspace` shortcut for "Delete" for me, which is a dealbreaker.

Comment: this is absolute gold. saved me

Comment: Natural - should have been the default.  Why keep a non-Natural thing as default

Comment: Perfect! Note that as of now (2022 March) it also includes the start/end mappings. (@MikeyN0's additional step is no longer needed)

Comment: This changing preset method should have been the accepted answer.

Comment: why isn't this the accepted answer? This definitly is the best one! Thx

Comment: I think *this* should be the accepted answer instead. The currently accepted answer is technically correct, but this one actually lands it by leveraging the preset mappings already available in iTerm to get you to feel like at home in iTerm, again. Thanks anyway!!

Comment: ure a lifesaver !!!

Comment: You made my day! Should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks, this is great. Why isn't this the default setting in iTerm2?

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Thank you

Comment: Yesss. And when it asks "Remove all key mappings before loading the preset" hit "Remove"

Comment: Confirmed working v3.4.20

Comment: Fresh Mac running Sonomo Prerelease, I don't see the presets. `brew reinstall --cask iterm2` surely won't do anything other than re-install it (and I installed it yesterday). I had to add shortcuts in "keys", observe they were getting overridden by a profile, then "profiles -> keys -> delete the 2 offending lines"

Comment: This preset should be set as default on iTerm2! Your answer should be accepted btw

Answer (score 196):

I like the following setup.

1. Preferences > Keys (or Preferences > Profiles > Keys)
2. Click the plus.

*move forward one word*

```
option+right
send escape sequence
f
```

*move back one word*

```
option+left
send escape sequence
b
```

*delete to beginning of word* ([credit](http://felipecsl.com/blog/2012/06/05/protip-delete-words-on-iterm2-mac-osx/))

```
option+delete
send hex code
0x1B 0x08
```

*delete to end of word*

```
fn+option+delete
send escape sequence
d
```

(I don't remember for sure, but I think I copied this answer from jherran's answer below and added more to it. I should have added the extra information in comments or suggested edits on that answer. I don't know how to improve the situation, but now it's known.)

Comment: On MacOS 10.12, I need to use hex code 0x17 to get delete to beginning of word

Comment: works like a charm with macOS 10.12 and zsh

Comment: best answer ever you have a beer from me :)

Comment: Consider upvoting jherran's answer. I think I just improved on their answer a little and probably should have suggested an edit instead of creating my own answer. I kind of feel like I stole it.

Comment: Referenced [this](http://www.kbdedit.com/manual/low_level_vk_list.html):  to do Esc-b, I had to send `0x1b 0x42`, and for Esc-f, I had to send `0x1b 0x46` :D

Comment: @Meredith you can either select "Send hex" and put `0x1b` before, which corresponds to `Esc`, or you can select "Send Escape" which prepends automatically `Esc`

Comment: I had to do the first two, but the last two were already setup by default. Thanks!

Comment: For delete to end of word, where does the code `d` come from?

Comment: Try pressing `ESC` and then pressing `d` with some editable text typed in after the cursor. Any text after the cursor should be deleted, until a space is encountered. Please read https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Introduction-and-Notation.html#Introduction-and-Notation and https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Readline-Killing-Commands.html#Readline-Killing-Commands

Comment: Why does 0x1B 0x08 (escape backspace) work as intended? Where can I redefine word boundary?

Comment: To answer your first question, if you read the two links in my last comment you can learn that pressing and releasing ESC, then pressing backspace, is notated as M-DEL, and that M-DEL will "Kill from the cursor [to] the start of the current word, or, if between words, to the start of the previous word." That behavior is built in to readline, the library that bash uses. I was not able to quickly find an answer to your second question.

Comment: I created the shortcuts as suggested but initially they didn't work as they were being overridden by keyboard shortcuts in my profile (see profile menu).  Deleting the respective entries in my profile seems to have done the trick.

Answer (score 51):

### To Get Forward (Alt-f), Backward (Alt-b) and Delete (Alt-d) Word

1. Open iTerm.
2. Go to iTerm > Preferences... > Profiles > Keys
3. Under Profile Shortcut Keys, click the + sign.
4. Type your key shortcut (option-b, option-f, option-d, option-left, etc.)
5. For Action, choose Send Escape Sequence.
6. Write b, d or f in the input field.

This works at least for bash. For zsh there are [other ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2212209) to navigate.

Comment: I tried to add an option+right shortcut and got a warning message about a conflict, because I didn't realize that you can configure keys both in Preferences > Keys > Global Shortcut Keys and also Preferences > Profiles > Keys > Profile Shortcut Keys. Configuring it in the default profile worked.

Comment: It works for zsh as well!

Comment: I think your answer (to the same solution) was the easiest to understand +1

Comment: Very useful explanation.

Comment: Perfect. You can also use Command+F etc so the "Alt" key is in the same position and no adjustment is necessary when switching between PC and Mac.

Comment: You might have saved my sanity.

Answer (score 24):

In build `3.3.12`, you can select the `Natural text editing` preset and it will add all the necessary escapes to make it feel like you're navigating text in any other app.

[image]

Comment: I have 3.4.15 and these options are gone (only defaults). Moreover, I can't find where to download these itermkeymaps...

Comment: Thank you for the screenshot. This made is easy for me to get this small feature back.

Comment: @rafraf, I had that problem too, but I was looking at the wrong screen. Make sure you're on Settings -> Profiles -> Keys, and not on Settings -> Keys -> Key Bindings!

Comment: How is this different from the Ricardo's THREE years older answer?

Answer (score 23):

Similar to other answers, but for Zsh it took me a while to find this:

If you are using Zsh, like Oh My Zsh, in iTerm then go to: Preferences > **Profiles** > Keys sub-menu

Click + sign

Add your shortcut combo, choose "Send Escape Sequence"

inputs for left and right below.

left:

```
[1;5D
```

right:

```
[1;5C
```

Comment: You saved my life mate

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me

Comment: Finally, a simple solution that works :D Thanks for sharing it with us!

Comment: This should be the answer. Upvoted.

Comment: Thanks, man, this is the best possible way IMO.

Comment: should be added to oh my zsh docs

Answer (score 11):

[image]

Open Preferences

Configure Left (and / or) Right Option key to send Esc+

If you messed with your presets, you may need to load the default preset (beware this could wipe your custom keybinds!)

[image]

If you see weird characters after you do this you may need to configure your ~/.inputrc or /etc/inputrc

Add this to your ~/.inputrc:

```
"\e[1;5C": forward-word
"\e[1;5D": backward-word
"\e[5C": forward-word
"\e[5D": backward-word
"\e\e[C": forward-word
"\e\e[D": backward-word
```

full example inputrc:

```
# /etc/inputrc - global inputrc for libreadline
# See readline(3readline) and `info rluserman' for more information.

# Be 8 bit clean.
set input-meta on
set output-meta on

# To allow the use of 8bit-characters like the german umlauts, uncomment
# the line below. However this makes the meta key not work as a meta key,
# which is annoying to those which don't need to type in 8-bit characters.

# set convert-meta off

# try to enable the application keypad when it is called.  Some systems
# need this to enable the arrow keys.
# set enable-keypad on

# see /usr/share/doc/bash/inputrc.arrows for other codes of arrow keys

# do not bell on tab-completion
# set bell-style none
# set bell-style visible

# some defaults / modifications for the emacs mode
$if mode=emacs

# allow the use of the Home/End keys
"\e[1~": beginning-of-line
"\e[4~": end-of-line

# allow the use of the Delete/Insert keys
"\e[3~": delete-char
"\e[2~": quoted-insert

# mappings for "page up" and "page down" to step to the beginning/end
# of the history
# "\e[5~": beginning-of-history
# "\e[6~": end-of-history

# alternate mappings for "page up" and "page down" to search the history
# "\e[5~": history-search-backward
# "\e[6~": history-search-forward

# mappings for Ctrl-left-arrow and Ctrl-right-arrow for word moving
"\e[1;5C": forward-word
"\e[1;5D": backward-word
"\e[5C": forward-word
"\e[5D": backward-word
"\e\e[C": forward-word
"\e\e[D": backward-word

$if term=rxvt
"\e[7~": beginning-of-line
"\e[8~": end-of-line
"\eOc": forward-word
"\eOd": backward-word
$endif

# for non RH/Debian xterm, can't hurt for RH/Debian xterm
# "\eOH": beginning-of-line
# "\eOF": end-of-line

# for freebsd console
# "\e[H": beginning-of-line
# "\e[F": end-of-line

$endif
```

Comment: Perfect... tks.

Comment: No problem! Glad it helps :)

Answer (score 4):

For new version of iterm 2 (3.4.4), I had to use the suggestion from https://coderwall.com/p/a8uxma/zsh-iterm2-osx-shortcuts. This work specifically for zsh

In zsh you can use ctrl + a/e to move to beginning/end of line and esc + W/B to move one word backward/forward, but that's not very handy.

Here is a solution to map ⌥ + ← / → and ⌘ + ← / → to work in iTerm2 as expected

Put this in your .zshrc

```
bindkey "[D" backward-word
bindkey "[C" forward-word
bindkey "^[a" beginning-of-line
bindkey "^[e" end-of-line
```

Comment: This is incomplete - as the URL also says you need to chnage things in iTerm - why do you think you do not need to do this?

Comment: Worked perfectly for me with iTerm 3.4.16 and zsh. Thanks!

Comment: As of Oct 3, 2022 - This works for me on Mac OS 12.6 and Iterm2 3.4.16

Answer (score 3):

You can set your terminal in vi mode with `set -o vi` to be able to use the usual vi motion commands (add the line in `.bash_profile` to store the setting permanently.)

So, as if in vi, you can hit `Esc`, then `b` to move one word backward (`w` for forward), go to the beginning of the line with `0`, or search a character backward with `F` + the char.

Hit `i` to go back to Normal mode and insert.

Those familiar with vi can do much more. [A cheat sheet can be found here](https://catonmat.net/ftp/bash-vi-editing-mode-cheat-sheet.txt).

Comment: vim solves everything! :D

Comment: Hitting `Esc` then `I` to just go once to the beginning of the line is slightly less convenient than `Ctrl-a` - this use case happens often when you just want to modify the command name. So I use vi mode with some keybinding changes in iTerm2 to map `Ctrl-A` and similar to escape sequence `Esc+0`. That way these cases are even faster as it ends in edit mode.

Answer (score 0):

Answer with more intuitive word breaks. If I have:

```
ls foo/bar foo/bar/baz
```

I want a word to be `foo/bar`, not `foo`. It took a while a while to get that working.

[From this](https://superuser.com/a/547131) I added to `.bash_profile`:

```
# Use Ctrl-g instead of Ctrl-f because Ctrl-f is mapped in macs to Find
bind '"\C-g":vi-fWord'
bind '"\C-b":vi-bWord'
```

From what I could tell, it's not possible to mention Option key in `.bash_profile`. So I had iTerm2 map from C-g -> Option-right, C-b -> Option-left:

[image: Screenshot of iTerm2 Preferences]

Answer (score 0):

For those how are interested this issue has the solution https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/-/issues/9806

Answer (score -1):

With iTerm2 3.1.4, I was able to setup the following without adding individual key mappings.

1. Go to **Preferences > Profiles > Keys**
2. Left/Right ⌥ Key: Select Esc+

With a new Terminal session you are now able to use:

<kbd>Option ⌥</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> to Get Forward

<kbd>Option ⌥</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd> to Get Forward

<kbd>Option ⌥</kbd> + <kbd>Delete ⌫</kbd> to Delete Word

Comment: How does this differ from the other highly voted answer? https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/293988/237