# Equivalent to Alt + dot on terminal

Tags: terminal, bash

On linux consoles I always use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> to get the last argument of the previous command in history.

for example if I had

```
ls /tmp/test
```

as last command, and if I type

```
rm Alt -
```

this will result in

```
rm /tmp/test
```

On an Apple Terminal, this doesen't work, is there an alternative?

Comment: You can also check Preferences > Settings > Keyboard > Use option as meta key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found an answer here:

[Equivalent to alt-. in terminal](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1391/equivalent-to-alt-in-terminal)

> <kbd>ESC</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> inserts the last argument and is the direct 
>   equivalent to <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> on Linux
>
> see https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/85152/31470