# Alt-. and vertical bar (pipe) on terminal

Tags: terminal, bash

On linux consoles I always use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> to get the last argument of the previous command in history.

for example if I had

```
ls /tmp/test
```

as last command, and if I type

```
rm Alt -
```

this will result in

```
rm /tmp/test
```

On an **Apple terminal**, this doesn't work by default but I found an answer here:

[Equivalent to alt-. in terminal](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1391/equivalent-to-alt-in-terminal)

> You have to change the Terminal’s behavior to the alt key acts as a meta key

Now there is a new problem: I cannot **access the pipe <kbd>|</kbd>** anymore (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd>)

How can I use both?

Comment: What keyboard layout do you have? On the US layout the pipe character is underneath the delete key

Comment: I use the german QWERTZ Layout, as I said,| is on Alt+7 normally

Answer (score 3, accepted):

esc+. inserts the last argument by default.

[iTerm](http://iterm.sourceforge.net/) can change just the other option key to meta:

[image]

Or if you change to the US layout, it doesn't have any ASCII characters under option.

For example `\e7\e.` normally inserts the seventh argument of the previous command, so there isn't really any way to get both.